# printing a list of type signatures

Tags: haskell, types

I want to be able to type the following in ghci:

```
map showTypeSignature [(+),(-),show]
```

I want ghci to return the following list of Strings:

```
["(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a","(-) :: Num a => a -> a -> a","show :: Show a => a -> String"]
```

Naturally, the first place that I run into trouble is that I cannot construct the first list, as the type signatures of the functions don't match. What can I do to construct such a list? How does ghci accomplish the printing of type signatures? Where is the ghci command :t defined (its source)?

Answer (score 9):

What you're asking for isn't really possible. You cannot easily determine the type signature of a Haskell term from within Haskell. At run-time, there's hardly any type information available. The GHCi command `:t` is a GHCi command, not an interpreted Haskell function, for a reason.

To do something that comes close to what you want you'll have to use GHC itself, as a library. GHC offers the GHC API for such purposes. But then you'll not be able to use arbitrary Haskell terms, but will have to start with a `String` representation of your terms. Also, invoking the compiler at run-time will necessarily produce an `IO` output.

Answer (score 7):

kosmikus is right, this doesn't really work out. And *shouldn't*, the static type system is one of Haskell's most distinguishing features!

However, you can emulate this for *monomorphic functions* quite well using the [`Dynamic` existential](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Dynamic.html):

```
showTypeSignature :: Dynamic -> String
showTypeSignature = show . dynTypeRep
```

> Prelude Data.Dynamic> `map showTypeSignature [toDyn (+), toDyn (-), toDyn (show)]`
>  
>   ["Integer -> Integer -> Integer","Integer -> Integer -> Integer","() -> [Char]"]

As you see ghci had to boil the functions down to monomorphic type here for this to work, which particularly for `show` is patently useless.

Answer (score 2):

The answers you have about why you can't do this are very good, but there may be another option.  If you don't care about getting a Haskell list, and just want to see the types of a bunch of things, you can [define a custom GHCi command](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/users_guide/ghci-commands.html), say `:ts`, that shows you the types of a list of things; to wit,

```
Prelude> :ts (+) (-) show
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
(-) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
show :: Show a => a -> String
```

To do this, we use `:def`; `:def NAME EXPR`, where `NAME` is an identifier and `EXPR` is a Haskell expression of type `String -> IO String`, defines the GHCi command `:NAME`.  Running `:NAME ARGS` evaluates `EXPR ARGS` to produce a string, and then runs the resulting string in GHCi.  This is less confusing than it sounds.  Here's what we do:

```
Prelude> :def ts return . unlines . map (":type " ++) . words
Prelude> :ts (+) (-) show
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
(-) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
show :: Show a => a -> String
```

What's going on?  This defines `:ts` to evaluate `return . unlines . map (":t " ++) . words`, which does the following:

- `words`: Takes a string and splits it on whitespace; *e.g.*, `"(+) (-) show"` becomes `["(+)", "(-)", "show"]`.
- `map (":type " ++)`: Takes each of the words from before and prepends `":type "`; *e.g.*, `["(+)", "(-)", "show"]` becomes `[":type (+)", ":type (-)", ":type show"]`.  Notice that we now have a list of GHCi commands.
- `unlines`: Takes a list of strings and puts newlines after each one; *e.g.*, `[":type (+)", ":type (-)", ":type show"]` becomes `":type (+)\n:type (-)\n:type show\n"`.  Notice that if we pasted this string into GHCi, it would produce the type signatures we want.
- `return`: Lifts a `String` to an `IO String`, because that's the type we need.

Thus, `:ts name₁ name₂ ... nameₙ` will evaluate `:type name₁`, `:type name₂`, …, `:type nameₙ` in succession and prints out the results.  Again, you can't get a real list this way, but if you just want to see the types, this will work.